# Displaying a specific object field in ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a ChoiceField in my form. The options that appear in the dropdown are equal to "industry name - frequency" (eg. Car Maintenance - Annual). I want the options in the dropdown to only be equal to the value in the frequency field of the choices that I initialize (eg. Annual).

**Models.py**

```
class IndustryFrequency(models.Model):    
    industryname = models.ForeignKey(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    frequency = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.industryname, self.frequency)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class UserOrderForm(forms.Form):
    frequency = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['frequency'].choices = [(t.id, t) for t in IndustryFrequency.objects.filter(industryname=industry)]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct your `choices`, in the form, give it `(t.id, t.frequency)`.

As such

```
[(t.id, t.frequency) for t in IndustryFrequency.objects.filter(industryname=industry)]
```

The tuple for choices stands for: (**value to hold**, **what to display in dropdown**).